# Would a PARI GP specific (teaching a bit hopefully) chat be popular?

Tags: discussion, chat, poll, computer-science

I'm thinking of opening a [PARI GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP) specific discussion, and teaching (I know a bit) chat room.

I've been made aware that chats freeze if left 14 days without activity, and I don't want that to happen to this chat if I open it. I'm not sure if there happen to be enough people interested in discussing, or learning (or helping teach it as I know what most abbreviations mean wording wise, but not all the number theory that may be relevant), the language, shortcuts, and secondary uses. So my question is this:

**Would a PARI GP specific chat be popular?**

**UPDATE** [The room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102811/pari-gp-programming) has now been handed over to people who care more about it than I do, clearly. .

Comment: I know it's supposed to be community wiki, I couldn't find the setting on mobile.

Comment: What is the motivation? Could you provide an introductory example of what is this?

Comment: The motivation is to teach users who want to learn, or help users improve speed of code. User @Peter got told to go higher on a now deleted question, I made a few improvements to their code on my end. it ran 3-4 times as fast in the same range I used in testing their code. It might be they can't think of easy ways to speed it up, or don't know of ways to make it more parallelizable, etc.

Comment: I would not expect this to be very popular. But it is also harmless, so if you are inclined then you might just go ahead and try it out.

Comment: They have a thread introducing it on mersenneforum, part of how I learned.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I just checked to confirm it also applies to meta. You can make your answers be community wiki, but not your questions. For example, with [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/562482) says "In the past, questions could be made community wiki by their authors or by certain automatic triggers but now the only means is by a moderator converting it to community wiki." Thus, you may wish to flag your question to ask a moderator to make this change.

Comment: I think it's a good idea, worth trying.  The few chatrooms I created were for quite narrow purposes, so I've not thought about what the automatic inactivity freeze entails.  Certainly it is possible to keep it activity if there is interest in a thread by more than one person.  (I wouldn't worry about making this Question CW; there's no reputation involved either way, and it's not likely that inviting edits to it will change the Community's response to the chatroom.)

Comment: my annoyance with trying is there are 5418 chatrooms in math, 48 are active the least is a programming related one.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102811/pari-gp-programming

Comment: The “PARI/GP programming” chat room has been [automatically frozen for inactivity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53642745#53642745).